# Экспорт базы данных (mysql workbench)

Tags: java, база-данных, github, jdbc

Есть небольшой проект с базой данных. Хочу закинуть его на GitHub. Как это лучше сделать? Создать дамп и скинуть в папку с проектом или есть еще какой-то способ?

Comment: Обычно используют мигрейшин тулы, такие как https://flywaydb.org/ и https://www.liquibase.org/

Comment: Обычно для таких вещей пишут скрипты.

Comment: обычно в средах разработки есть экспорт таблиц и схем, они генерят скрипты по созданию объектов в бд и после заполнения данными. Получается большой файл sql, в котором куча insert-ов идут один за одним